# Is possible to get the details such as utm_source/utm_medium etc from a Google Analytic Cookie?

Tags: angularjs, google-analytics

I'm using angular to get the cookie:

```
$cookies.get('_ga');
```

But it only prints a series of numbers that I dont understand.
Example:

```
GA1.1.332332589.7892389403
```

Is it possible to get the utm_source, utm_medium etc. from this cookie? If so, how?

NOTE: I was going to use ga.js but the [docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/) said it's deprecated and I should start using analytics.js instead. But I just want to get the utm_source and utm_medium and it seems like analytics.js only stores `_ga` cookie and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

What you see there is the cid (Client ID). Analytics use this Client ID to identify sessions and users. You don't get Source or Medium from the Cookie.

Go to Network, there you will find `?collect...`-URLs in this URLs you maybe (depends on your set up) find the Information you need.